# Cassandra - Java driver: QueryBuilder, ask for multiple composite keys in a where clause

Tags: java, cassandra, key-value-store

I am new to Cassandra. I want to programatically (QueryBuilder) query for multiple rows at once in a table with a composite primary key.

Something like:

Assume that in `TABLE PRIMARY KEY(key1,key2)`

```
Select * from TABLE where (key1=a AND key2=b) OR (key1=c AND key2=d)
```

Thanks in advance.

Altober

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement will never work because the OR keyword do not exist in Cassandra. There's unfortunately no alternatives at the moment unless you use a custom index such as [lucene](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index)